React native expo firebase google login build issue
I am building react native expo app and am integration firebase and @react-native-google-signin/google-sign, but when running npx expo run ios I am getting error. I have updated the Podfile as well these are the lines I have added in Podfile
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreInternal', :modular_headers => true

and
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
        target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
          if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
            flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
            flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
            file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
          end
        end
      end
    end

but the error still persists
I tried deleting the node_modules and ios folder as well as run pod repo update also run rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. I have also tried pod deintegrate and pod install. but nothing works. I am using macbook air m1.
